# React + TypeScript Syntax: Dynamically change container component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a clean way to write this kind of syntax below in React+TypeScript? When I do this, I get the following error.

```
JSX element type 'Container' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

Code:

```
const Container = this.props.useFoo ? <Foo {...fooProps}></Foo> : <div></div>;

return (
        <Container>
            <div {...someAttrs}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </Container>
);
```

I know I can define the container tag dynamically with a string, i.e. `Tag = "div"`, and use `<Tag>...</Tag>`, but this doesn't seem to work for components. The only way I can do this is to save the child content to a variable, and do the following which I found it verbose and ugly.

```
const content = <div {...someAttrs}>{this.props.children}</div>;

return (
    <>
        {this.props.useFoo ? <Foo {...fooProps}>{content}</Foo> : <div>{content}</div>}
    </>
);
```

**EDIT:**

I decided to go with this syntax:

```
const container = (content) => {
    return this.props.useFoo ? <Foo {...fooProps}>{content}</Foo> : <div>{content}</div>;
};

return container(
    <div {...someAttrs}>
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

⚠ *Note that I am just getting started with "TypeScript" (using React).*

It seems like you are assigning an rendered Component instance to `Container` instead of specifying what the shape (class) of container should be.

So you need to pass the class or the intrinsic string, `"div"` and set the container as `React.ReactType` (which can be a class, functional component or intrinsic ones like `div`, `p`, `span`, etc).

```js
function Demo(props: DemoProps) {
  const Container: React.ReactType = props.useFoo ? Foo : "div";

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

You can check the demo on Sandbox.

[image: Edit so.answer.54448317]

---

Full source in case Sandbox link fails to work.

#### Code

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

interface DemoProps {
  useFoo?: boolean;
  children: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const Foo = () => <div>Foo</div>;

function Demo(props: DemoProps) {
  const Container: React.ReactType = props.useFoo ? Foo : "div";

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
    </Container>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Demo useFoo>This is a demo App</Demo>
      <Demo>This is a demo App</Demo>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### Result

[image: demo result]

☝ You can see the when `useFoo` was used, container overwrote the children content.

Comment: That's neat. But, you are not passing `fooProps` to the component `Foo`. Is that still possible with this syntax? In my case, `Foo` comes from a separate file, and `fooProps` is dynamically created inside the `Demo` component.

Comment: @CookieMonster No. because you need to pass `fooProps` to an instance. You can pass the `fooProps` in `Container` but that'd clutter if `useFoo` is false.  Then you are stuck with the 2nd "verbose and ugly" version...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first example is that you're passing the already rendered component, instead of a reference to it (to be rendered later), the way to fix it is:

```
// imports ...

function Foo(props) {
  console.log('using foo')
  return <main>{props.children}</main>
}

function Baz(props) {
  console.log('using baz')
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}

function ConditionalComponent(props) {
  const Container = props.useFoo ? Foo : Baz;

  return (
    <Container>
      {props.children}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ReactNode, FC, ComponentType, HTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
  // this can be any HTML element. default is "div" that is why optional
  el?: ComponentType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>;
}

// Element is alias for el. default is "div"
const Container: FC<Props> = ({ children, el: Element= "div" }) => {
  return <Element className="px-6 mx-auto max-w-8xl">{children}</Element>;
};

export default Container;
```